# How can I extract the QQPLOT of the post.check function in GJRM package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gamlss

This is the code and I want to extract the QQplot of this Plot into post.check(out). Additionally, How can I change the title of the qqplot?

```
library(GJRM)
set.seed(0)
n <- 400
x1 <- round(runif(n))
x2 <- runif(n)
x3 <- runif(n)
f1 <- function(x) cos(pi*2*x) + sin(pi*x)
y1 <- -1.55 + 2*x1 + f1(x2) + rnorm(n)
dataSim <- data.frame(y1, x1, x2, x3)
eq.mu <- y1 ~ x1 + s(x2) + s(x3)
eq.s <- ~ s(x3)
fl <- list(eq.mu, eq.s)
out <- gamlss(fl, data = dataSim)
conv.check(out)
post.check(out)
```

[image]

Applying the idea below, the result is:

```
p1 <- post.check(out)
plot(qqnorm(p1$qr), main = "Normal")
```

[image]

In my case, I want only one plot. I would like to know that because I want to wrap only the qqplots not the histograms. The next code is not reproducible, it is only to show what I have.

```
DA.mrf<-as.ggplot(~post.check(DA.gamlss.mrf.6, main = "Dagum",cex=0.7,cex.axis=0.7))
GA.mrf<-as.ggplot(~post.check(GA.gamlss.mrf.6, main = "Gamma"))
LN.mrf<-as.ggplot(~post.check(LN.gamlss.mrf.4, main = "LogNormal"))
IG.mrf<-as.ggplot(~post.check(IG.gamlss.mrf.4, main = "Inverse Gaussian"))
WE.mrf<-as.ggplot(~post.check(WE.gamlss.mrf.6, main = "Weibull"))

plot_grid(DA.mrf, GA.mrf, LN.mrf,
          IG.mrf, WE.mrf, ncol=3,label_size = 5)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's much more helpful if you can provide a reproducible example (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for details).

From the code you have posted, it seems that you can recreate the QQ-plot from each model separately. For example, for your first model `DA.gamlss.mrf.6`, you can use:

```
p1 <- post.check(DA.gamlss.mrf.6)
plot(qqnorm(p1$qr), main = "Your Choice of Title Goes Here")
```

Note that, depending on what your model is, you may need to replace `qr` above with `qr1` and `qr2`. See `help(post.check)` from the `GJRM` package for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I know a reproducible example is necessary, but my data and equations are too long. I am going to post an example of the package. thanks, again

Comment: No problem. Based on your updated example, `plot(qqnorm(p1$qr))` should cover your needs, and the plot's title can be customized via the `main` argument.

Comment: Yes, it works. The problem is that I want only one plot. This function prints 2 qqplots. How can I extract only one of them?

Comment: For some reason, it keeps the previous graphical parameters which have two charts per plot. Try running `par(mfrow = c(1,1))` and then `plot(qqnorm(p1$qr), main = "Normal")`. That should give you a single plot.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The solution was easy. Thanks a lot!! Have a great time!!